# Opening Sound Files In .Net

Tags: c#

need a bit of help here. Does anyone know how to open files such as PCM, PRF, PAD, KMP, STY, and PCG in .Net? It doesn't matter if it is included in .Net or if it is from a third-party library. I need to be able to view their content, edit them, and convert them from one format to another.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is going to be the library of choice here. It's the easiest one to work with on the market that I've found. Further, we have an application in production today serving 14K+ users with that library, so it's production ready.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this one.

Answer (score 3):

[Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net/) allows to convert many types of audio files with help DirectShow filters. [There are many examples of the use of the library.](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx)